# How do I run cron/scheduled task in Nextjs 9?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I'm building an app with Nextjs and I'm using pages/api directory for my api endpoints. The server entry/root is hidden for me. How do I immediately run the scheduled task with node-cron when my app is deployed then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. What you can do are scheduled tasks with the node-cron library. You have to put your task which you want to schedule in your next.config.js file like so:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', function () {
  console.log('Say scheduled hello')
});

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but it doesn't seem like there's a good way to import other app modules from this file. For example, I had hoped to run some async code that is also used by the backend APIs.

Comment: I know. Every file must be exported as a module if you want to use it inside the next.config.js file. There is also sadly no typescript support for the next.config.js file. An alternative would be nice but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that you keep the next.config.js pretty simple as stated here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5318#issuecomment-540629772

So if using a custom server inside next.js is not recommended either, the best solution would be to use a third party or boot up a second server

Answer (score 1):

You can use their [Custom Server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) hook to include your task scheduling logic during the server initialization. But keep in mind that this is not recommended:

> Before deciding to use a custom server please keep in mind that it should only be used when the integrated router of Next.js can't meet your app requirements. A custom server will remove important performance optimizations, like serverless functions and Automatic Static Optimization.